# SQL Server : update multiple rows dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-update

I want to update multiple rows in my database, the values might be different. Imagine this table:

```
Username   FirstName   LastName 
-------------------------------
user1      John        Doe 
user2      Jane        Doe
user3      bill        gates
```

If I want to update the table so it looks like this:

```
Username   FirstName   LastName 
-------------------------------
user1      John        Deer 
user2      Jane        Farmer
user3      Gill        Bates
```

Is it best to use one `UPDATE` statement for each user? Or is it possible to do this with one query?

Also is it possible to put it in a stored procedure and provide a collection of values?

Second question is it best to check if the values are changed before doing an update? Or just update everyone even if the value is the same?

I am currently using SQL Server 2005 and C# for the application if that is relevant.

Comment: While technically possible to make this into one query, you'd have an insane WHERE clause or CASE logic to contend with.  Bulk Updates are best when you have 1 criteria to apply to multiple values... For instance, it would be good to have an update statement on multiple rows if you wanted to update all first and last names to Proper casing or if you needed to change certain last names to equal the value of another column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
declare @TempTable1 table (UserName nvarchar(128) primary key, FirstName nvarchar(128), LastName(128))

insert into @TempTable1
select 'user1', 'John', 'Deer' union all
select 'user2', 'Jane', 'Farmer' union all
select 'user3', 'Gill', 'Bate'

update table1 set
    FirstName = t2.FirstName,
    LastName = t2.LastName
from table1 as t
    inner join @TempTable1 as t2 on t2.UserName = t.UserName
```

Or if you want to update only changed fields

```
update table1 set
    FirstName = isnull(t2.FirstName, t.FirstName),
    LastName = isnull(t2.LastName, t.LastName)
from table1 as t
    inner join @TempTable1 as t2 on t2.UserName = t.UserName
```

For C# client application I think usual way is to create procedure

```
create procedure sp_Table1_Update
(
    @UserName nvarchar(128),
    @FirstName nvarchar(128),
    @LastName nvarchar(128)
)
as
begin
    update table1 set
        FirstName = @FirstName,
        LastName = @LastName
    where UserName = @UserName
end
```

and then call it from your application for each user

Comment: ok, thats what i basicly are doing now. Was wondering if it was possible to run one query for multiple users and whats the best way. Running one query for each user is the easiest for me, but is not sure whats best in regard to performance.

Comment: Im just going to run it this way, it seems simplest for now. Later i can do some profiling if the performance is bad.

Comment: @LasseVabeRolstad well it depends on how much users you want to be updated at once. If you have more than hundred rows to be updated from client (what seems a little strange to me) you may consider using xml to update all rows by one statement

Answer (score 0):

I'd create separate queries for the individual users:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET FirstName = 'John', 'LastName = 'Doe' WHERE FirstName = 'John' 
    AND 'LastName = 'Deer' AND 'UserName = 'user1'
```

etc.

You have unique usernames, so in theory it should not be necessary to update values that did not change. However, you can always build it in as an extra safety precaution.

Comment: This query i have already created, but this is just an example of the real table. Its about 300 000 rows. So my question was if it is performance wise best to check if the row has changed before doing and update or if its just faster to update the row with now regard for what its previous value was.

Comment: If it's performance you need, then checking in advance whether the column eneds to be updated or not would be a good idea. I'd do something dynamically then, where you write a generic update statement, and perform the check on the column. If it needs to be updated, append the column to the statement, otherwise skip it.